# JQuery: How to iterate in all span having a specific class

Tags: jquery

### please see my html first

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>City</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Students_0__ID" name="Students[0].ID" type="text" value="1" />
       <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[0].ID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   </td>
   <td>
     <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Students_0__Name" name="Students[0].Name" type="text" value="JoyDev" />
     <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[0].Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   </td>
   <td>
     <select class="edit-mode" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field StateID must be a number." data-val-required="The StateID field is required." id="Students_0__StateID" name="Students[0].StateID"><option value="">-- Select States--</option>
       <option selected="selected" value="1">WestBengal</option>
       <option value="2">Bihar</option>
       <option value="3">Orrisa</option>
     </select>
     <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[0].StateID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <select class="edit-model" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CityID must be a number." data-val-required="The CityID field is required." id="Students_0__CityID" name="Students[0].CityID"><option value="">--Select States--</option>
         <option selected="selected" value="1">Alipur</option>
         <option value="2">Asansol</option>
         <option value="3">Andul</option>
      </select>
      <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[0].CityID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Students_1__ID" name="Students[1].ID" type="text" value="1" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[1].ID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
         <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Students_1__Name" name="Students[1].Name" type="text" value="Mukti" />
         <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[1].Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
       </td>
       <td>
          <select class="edit-mode" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field StateID must be a number." data-val-required="The StateID field is required." id="Students_1__StateID" name="Students[1].StateID"><option value="">-- Select States--</option>
          <option value="1">WestBengal</option>
          <option selected="selected" value="2">Bihar</option>
          <option value="3">Orrisa</option>
        </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[1].StateID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
      </td>
       <td>
          <select class="edit-model" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CityID must be a number." data-val-required="The CityID field is required." id="Students_1__CityID" name="Students[1].CityID"><option value="">--Select States--</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="1">Janpur</option>
            <option value="2">Madhubani</option>
            <option value="3">Kanti</option>
          </select>
          <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[1].CityID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ID must be a number." data-val-required="The ID field is required." id="Students_2__ID" name="Students[2].ID" type="text" value="1" />
              <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[2].ID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </td>

        <td>
           <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Students_2__Name" name="Students[2].Name" type="text" value="Somnath" />
           <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[2].Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
           <select class="edit-mode" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field StateID must be a number." data-val-required="The StateID field is required." id="Students_2__StateID" name="Students[2].StateID"><option value="">-- Select States--</option>
             <option value="1">WestBengal</option>
             <option value="2">Bihar</option>
             <option selected="selected" value="3">Orrisa</option>
           </select>
           <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[2].StateID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
         </td>
         <td>
           <select class="edit-model" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CityID must be a number." data-val-required="The CityID field is required." id="Students_2__CityID" name="Students[2].CityID"><option value="">--Select States--</option>
             <option value="1">Chandapur</option>
             <option selected="selected" value="2">Dhankauda</option>
             <option value="3">Konarak</option>
           </select>
           <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Students[2].CityID" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
          </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
```

i want to iterate all span in table having a class `field-validation-error`
i tried this way but no luck.

```
$("table td span[class='field-validation-error']").each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("data-valmsg-for"));
    $(this).addClass(".hidden");//Add class hidden to hide  @@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.xyz) if using bootstrap , else use css
    var inputID = $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for");//get the id of the input field for which this validation prompted
    var validationMessage = $(this).html();//Get validation message for input filed which is prompted
    //$("#" + inputID).tooltip({ 'trigger': 'hover', 'title': validationMessage });//Trigger the tooltip now, if using bootstrap.

    //******OR*******

    $("#" + inputID).attr("title", validationMessage);
});
```

i try to iterate in all span with a specific class and try to add class called `hidden` and also try to read attribute value from `data-valmsg-for`.
also try to add some text to html control's title attribute `$("#" + inputID).attr("title", validationMessage);` but not working my code.

when i am testing code then found control is not going to this iterate `$("table td span[class='field-validation-error']").each()` i definitely made some mistake in jquery code. so looking for guidance. thanks

Comment: Your attempt fails because `span[class='field-validation-error']` selects `<span />` elements where the `class` attribute has exactly the value `field-validation-error` but your `<span />` elements all have more than one class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dot `.` that is the class selector `$("table td span.field-validation-error")`, and use **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** to get data attributes :

```
$(this).data("valmsg-for");
```

Instead of :

```
$(this).attr("data-valmsg-for");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: my span look like `<span class="text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Students[0].ID">
<span class="" for="Students_0__ID">The ID field is required.</span>
</span>` how to get this text `The ID field is required` from child span ?

Comment: You can use `text()` function, e.g : `$('.field-validation-error').text();`, but in your code it should be `$(this).text();`.

Comment: why this code ` $("#" + inputID).attr("title", validationMessage);` not working. i try to add some text to controls title property but not working.

Comment: my textbox id looks like `Students_0__ID` with which i am trying to add some text to its title attribute.

Comment: Check if the `validationMessage` is not empty, since the syntax is correct.

Comment: i hard code the value `$("#" + inputID).attr("title", "Hello");` but still no luck.

Comment: Work in my side with hard coding check https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/17/, you can see in console the attribute changed.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `.` notation when dealing with class selection. Thus you can select your span elements as following:

```
$('table td span.field-validation-error').each(function () {
  // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.`(dot) specifies that you want to match the class attribute of the span tag.

```
$('table td span.field-validation-error').each(function)
```

JQuery borrows it's [selectors from the W3 CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html). You can see the complete JQuery selectors documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 $("table td .field-validation-error")
```

this selector.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10907698)

Comment: @JonSurrell No, it *is* an answer. But not correct.

Comment: @GertArnold I usually interpret "try this…" as a suggestion rather than and answer. Like you didn't want to take the time to investigate and write a real answer.

Comment: @JonSurrell I don't know why so many people write "try this" answers. Sometimes it's because they don't have the OP's code, so they can't compile/run their suggestion an hence feel insecure. Sometimes they're just throwing in a wild guess. My gut feeling told me this one was in the first category. (Not that I would ever give an answer like this before suggesting it in a comment first.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.field-validation-error').each(function () {
   var spn = $(this);
   spn.css({
       //your code.
   })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table td span.field-validation-error').each(function () {
    // your code
});
```

Use `.` to select by class